# Backbone: Binding to the view's wrapping div

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a backbone IndexView which calls a TaskView for each 'task' model. I'd like to bind an event to the li element that *wraps* the taskview. So for example, the 'className' attribute is 'task', and I want to trigger an event on '.task'.

I can bind from the parent (IndexView) view, but I'd like access to information inside the clicked view, which I'm guessing means the event should be bound to the child TaskView(?)

(Also, DOM classes *inside* the actual tasks template can be accessed...just not the wrapping .task li)

Any ideas appreciated - code below.

### CHILD VIEW

Backbonescaffolddemo.Views.Tasks ||= {}

```
class Backbonescaffolddemo.Views.Tasks.TaskView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/tasks/task"]

  tagName: "li"
  className: "task"

  events:
    "click .task"    : "demoMethod"

  initialize: () ->
    _.bindAll(this, 'demoMethod', 'render')
    console.log @
    #@showTask()
    @el.id = 'sort_order_' + @model.get('id') if @model

  destroy: () ->
    @model.destroy()
    this.remove()
    return false

  demoMethod: () ->
    console.log 'Work dammit, work. Arghhh'

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(@model.toJSON() ))    
    return this
```

### PARENT VIEW

```
Backbonescaffolddemo.Views.Tasks ||= {}

class Backbonescaffolddemo.Views.Tasks.IndexView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/tasks/index"]
  id: "taskList"

  events: 
    "keyup #searchTasks" : "searchTasks"

  initialize: () ->
    _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'sortable', 'task_id_from_element', 'addAll', 'searchTasks', 'updateSort', 'sortable', 'render')
    @options.tasks.bind('reset', @addAll)
    @options.tasks.bind('reset', @sortable)
    @options.tasks.bind('add', @render)
    @updateSort()
    @sortable()

  #...

  addAll: () ->
    @options.tasks.each(@addOne)

  addOne: (task) ->
    view = new Backbonescaffolddemo.Views.Tasks.TaskView({model: task})
    $(@el).append(view.render().el)

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(tasks: @options.tasks.toJSON() ))
    @addAll() 
    return this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh - found it. A straight-out "click" : "demoMethod" (with no specified DOM scope) does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're adding the div that wraps the TaskView.

By default, Backbone views are wrapped in a `div` but since you set the `tagName` on your TaskView to `li`, it's going to be wrapped in a `li` and not a `div`.

Comment: My bad - grammatical error, meant 'li', not 'div'. Edited above